# Spring batch 2.1.8 multiple steps execution in parallel has limitation

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to execute multiple steps in parallel using a single Job in Spring batch. Here is how my configuration looks.

```
<job id="gmegdc1" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" >
        <split id="splitStep" task-executor="taskExecutor">
            <flow>
                <step id="step1" parent="simpleStep1">
                    <tasklet ref="gdcTasklet1" task-executor="taskExecutor1" throttle-limit="6" />          
                </step>
            </flow>
            <flow>
                <step id="step2" parent="simpleStep2">
                    <tasklet ref="gdcTasklet2" task-executor="taskExecutor2" throttle-limit="6" />
                </step>
            </flow>
            <flow>
                <step id="step3" parent="simpleStep3">
                    <tasklet ref="gdcTasklet3" task-executor="taskExecutor3" throttle-limit="6" />
                </step>
            </flow>
            <flow>
                <step id="step4" parent="simpleStep4">
                    <tasklet ref="gdcTasklet4" task-executor="taskExecutor4" throttle-limit="6" />
                </step>
            </flow>
        </split>    
    </job>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="25" />                  
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="25" />        
    </bean>

<bean id="taskExecutor1" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
    <bean id="taskExecutor2" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
    <bean id="taskExecutor3" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
    <bean id="taskExecutor4" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
```

I wanted to run 6 threads for each step. With this configuration every time I start the job only 8 threads in different combination of steps were running at a time. Due to this some of the steps were not getting executed and also I am getting the potential of all threads running. Not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: did you have a look at partitioning? See http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning

Answer (score 0):

may be too late to answer. But might help others having the same issue.

If you have integrated the spring batch admin project with your spring batch application, then it is that admin that is limiting the number of threads to 8. I removed the spring batch admin dependencies and made my spring batch as a simple spring web app and now the number of threads crossed 8 and reaches the maxpoolsize.

One other thing to mention is take a look at the throttle-limit configuration in tasklet tag.